# Gradient is None with tf2.3 using a simple network

Tags: tensorflow2.0, gradienttape

I am new to tensorflow and I was trying to learn how to use tf.GradientTape() with a simple dense network. Here is my code, xxx represent different inputs:

```
    import tensorflow as tf

    model_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=3)
    model = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4,name="test")(model_input)
    model = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2)(model)
    model = tf.keras.models.Model(model_input, model)
    x = tf.constant([[1., 2., 3.]])
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        tape.watch(x)
        tape.watch(model.get_layer("test").output)
        tape.watch(model.get_layer("test").input)
        y = model(x)# Forward pass

    grad = tape.gradient(xxx, xxx)
    print("grad:",grad)
```

And the next is the results in different inputs:

```
    grad = tape.gradient(y, x)
```

`1. grad: tf.Tensor(\[\[0.8856039 1.8219335 1.1762565\]\], shape=(1, 3), dtype=float32)`

```
    grad = tape.gradient(y, model.get_layer("test").trainable_weights)
```

2. `grad: \[\<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 4), dtype=float32, numpy= array(\[\[-1.08425   , -0.10035539, -1.4471946 , -0.15857029\], \[-2.1685    , -0.20071077, -2.8943892 , -0.31714058\], \[-3.25275   , -0.30106616, -4.3415837 , -0.47571087\]\], dtype=float32)\>, \<tf.Tensor: shape=(4,), dtype=float32, numpy=array(\[-1.08425   , -0.10035539, -1.4471946 , -0.15857029\], dtype=float32)\>\]`

```
    grad = tape.gradient(y, model.get_layer("test").input)
```

3. grad: None

```
    grad = tape.gradient(y, model.get_layer("test").output)
```

4. grad: None

I want to know why (3) and (4) were 'None'.

Can I use layer.input/output to calculate the gradients? I think the answer is yes because I have seen another example showing here, [Grad-CAM in keras](https://keras.io/examples/vision/grad_cam/). In this example, layer.output was used.